# copy files from one folder to another but code is not working

Tags: perl

Please check the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Cwd;        
use warnings;    
use Net::FTP;    
use File::Copy;    
use File::Path;    
use Time::Local;     
use File::Basename;    
use strict;    
my $directory = "/media/Songs/Perl/test";    
my $path = "/media/Songs/Perl/test_sort";    
opendir(DIR,$directory);    
my @files = readdir(DIR);    
closedir(DIR);    
foreach my $t (@files)
{    
    copy($t,$path); //copying files
}
```

Comment: "Please check the code" is not a question, its a request. If you want to avoid downvotes, pinpoint the problem in your code, include error messages, explain how the program is not working the way you want.

Answer (score 8):

This is my revision of your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

my $source_dir = "/media/Songs/Perl/test";
my $target_dir = "/media/Songs/Perl/test_sort";

opendir(my $DIR, $source_dir) || die "can't opendir $source_dir: $!";  
my @files = readdir($DIR);

foreach my $t (@files)
{
   if(-f "$source_dir/$t" ) {
      #Check with -f only for files (no directories)
      copy "$source_dir/$t", "$target_dir/$t";
   }
}

closedir($DIR);
```

Comment: thnx Miguel Prz ....its working now..

Comment: What good is it to provide an answer without explanations?

Comment: It is self-explanatory, isn't it?

Comment: No, it isn't. There are many subtleties, explanations and recommendations that can be added. The point of StackOverflow is to teach people things, not to solve their problems for them.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer

Comment: @MiguelPrz: Thanks. Have edited your answer appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

The `readdir` function takes a bit of post-processing to be useful. It returns all entries in that directory, including `.` (this directory) and `..` parent directory. The strings returned are not full paths from your $PWD.

1. Filter out unwanted items: Regex to match parent and self links

   ```
   my @files = grep !/\A\.\.?\z/, readdir DIR;
   ```

   or only select simple `-f`iles (no directories nor fun like pipes, sockets…)

   ```
   my @files = grep -f "$directory/$_", readdir DIR;
   ```
2. Make absolute paths:

   Really, one should use `Path::Class` or `File::Spec`. But if you are careful, and don't care about portability, then

   ```
   for my $file (@files) {
     my $source = "$directory/$file";
     ...;
   }
   ```

   may be good enough.

The `copy` function takes two *filenames*, not a file and a target directory. And you should perform error checking:

```
for my $file (@files) {
  my $source = "$directory/$file";
  my $target = "$path/$file";
  copy $source => $target or warn "Copy of $file failed: $!";
}
```

Comment: No. The `copy` subroutine from `File::Copy` does not require two filenames. It will use the original file name if the second argument is a directory. +1 for the explanation though.